# Can dd be used to copy an SSD with an OS?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, dd

The OS in question is Windows 8.1

Both laptops have 100+ gig SSDs

Now suppose I really don't want to bother installing the OS again, can I just use a linux USB stick, dd the whole SSD drive to external storage and dd it back to the new SSD on the new laptop?

Will this work?

If so, what kind of issues would arise? If the second SSD is larger will I be able to extend partition or have to make a new one? etc.

Comment: Why don't you use Clonezilla or some other cloning tool? I'm not sure if dd is going to work. But is there any special reason for not using a cloning tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Do remember to use `/dev/sdX` to copy the drive and not  `/dev/sdX1` as this would copy only a partition within the drive.

Comment: Note that because the partition information is copied as well, you'll want the host and dest drives to have the same capacities. Else, you will run into issues with your last partition.

Comment: Bigger is also OK; you'd just have unused space after your last partition. Usually you can grow that last partition, or otherwise you can create a new one in the extra space.

Comment: yeah, but it still requires some extra work. The simplest setup is to have drives the same capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is specifically YES.....however I have found that you will have to reGRUB your newly copied image for it to be usable again.  Not a big problem but something to be aware of.

One problem with the dd approach is that the disk architectures need to be identical in order for the resulting image to work properly.  I'd recommend using an imaging technique that could be used to move an image directly to a different architecture.  There are a few programs on the market that are relatively cheap and effective.

Comment: I do this all the time between an SSD and a larger hard drive (keeping the same size partition as the SSD) and have never had to re-GRUB.  The disks are exact duplicates including UUIDs.  Of course, I'm assuming you're copying the entire drive, not just a partition (as mentioned above).